# Array with multiple linked objects in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, sorting

This might be too primitive, but for my use case, I need to maintain an array in which two attributes are linked to each other... For example - If I want to do Score gathering... Then I need an array which has scores and corresponding player names as each element.

So, when I do `Array.Sort(PlayerScorearray)` I even need the playername to be sorted in the order so that if I want to know the player with lowest score, I just go for the first element and then go to the corresponding player name.. Is it possible to do it in a simpler way? My mind can't think of a simple way to do this.

Edit : I am using C# for scripts

Comment: Do you mean you have two separate arrays? One for the score value and the other for the player name? If so, you will surely be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964234/sorting-an-array-related-to-another-array) Otherwise, the `Sort` method accepts an instance of a class implementing the `IComparer` interface, so you can define your own compare method [see here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: For now, I was digging onto Dictionary which is way more complicated for a beginner like me, but... Wow! That double array might work well for me, I ll try it out once. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

1. Make a tuple type that combines both pieces of information

   `public struct ScoreEntry {
        public string playerName;
        public float score;
    }`

   Then you can sort them using a custom comparer, like so:

   `Array.Sort(scoreEntries, 
              (ScoreEntry a, ScoreEntry b) => { return a.score - b.score; } );`

   Or, to be more concise, you can make your ScoreEntry implement [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx) so that the default Sort knows how to sort them without this helper. ;)
2. You can use the Array.Sort overload that takes two arrays and sorts them in parallel:

   `Array.Sort(scores, playerNames);`

   (In my experience, this method is not very efficient, but your mileage may vary)

Both these strategies are easily found by reviewing the [MSDN documentation on sorting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort(v=vs.110).aspx) or doing a [simple Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=c%23%20sort%20two%20arrays) (sorting is a pretty bread-and-butter operation, so there's tons of information out there about how to tackle it) - so please don't neglect to do your own research.

Comment: I never thought Array sort would have overload with key and item types... Looked into it... Solved my problem!